# ImageButton position

Tags: java, android, layout, imagebutton

I'm trying to put an ImageButton on my app. This is a sort of hidden button, is the blue rectangle. Now, i want to put this button right and down, but as you can see, i can't, because there are two space to the right and down. (Where there are the two green arrow). How can I remove that space? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Does the container view of the ImageButton has padding?

Answer (score 0):

Adjust the padding of the View that contains the button.

**Layout XML**:
`android:padding`

Comment: Welcome to SO! This is not an answer since there could be several things causing this issue and without seeing the xml you don't know this is the problem.